# Get logs that contain only JSON

Tags: java, logstash

I have a file containing logs log4j, I just can’t write a filter for logstash, which will return logs that contain only JSON

```
input {
   file {
      path => "C:/logs/inlog.log"
   }
} 
filter {
  #A lot of what I tried to write
}
output {
   file {
      path => "C:/logs/outlog.log"
   }
}
```

As a result, we need a filter that displays logs containing json. Json logs are marked as trace

example logs:

```
[2019/08/02 11:21:52.472 MSK] [ 4] INFO  ru.dmko.logstash.util.Utils - Initialized timer 'MyProject' with interval - 60000 
[2019/08/02 11:21:53.769 MSK] [ 4] INFO  ru.dmko.logstash.EventHandlerBean - EventHandler started 
[2019/08/02 11:21:56.535 MSK] [21] INFO  ru.dmko.logstash.processors.MessageProcessorBean - {"glossary": {"title": "example glossary", "GlossDiv": {"title": "S", "GlossList": {"GlossEntry": {"ID": "SGML", "SortAs": "SGML", "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language", Acronym": "SGML", "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986", "GlossDef": { "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.", "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]}, "GlossSee": "markup"}}}} 
[2019/08/02 11:21:56.551 MSK] [21] INFO  ru.dmko.logstash.processors.MessageProcessorBean - Equal messages 
[2019/08/02 11:21:56.613 MSK] [21] INFO  ru.dmko.logstash.processors.MessageProcessorBean - {"glossary": {"title": "example glossary", "GlossDiv": {"title": "S", "GlossList": {"GlossEntry": {"ID": "SGML", "SortAs": "SGML", "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language", Acronym": "SGML", "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986", "GlossDef": { "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.", "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]}, "GlossSee": "markup"}}}}
```

Of these, you only need to see two containing json

Comment: Could you provide an example of the pattern of your logs? At trace level are more logs that aren't json?

Comment: @Ezequiel added to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this to pick out the JSON

```
grok { match => { "message" => "%{JAVACLASS} - (?={)%{GREEDYDATA:json}" } }
```

If you want to you can drop {} messages that have "_grokparsefailure" in [tags]

If you fix the JSON to be valid (add opening " to Acronym and add trailing }) you can parse it using

```
json { source => json }
```

Another (cheaper) possibility, depending on whether " - " ever occurs in other contexts in the events is

```
    dissect { mapping => { "message" => "%{} - %{json}" } }
    if [json] =~ /^{/ {
        json { source => json }
    } else {
        drop {}
    }
```

Comment: Instead of using grok on all the lines, perhaps it would be more efficient to just use a conditional: `if [message] =~ /(?:[a-zA-Z$_][a-zA-Z$_0-9]*\.)*[a-zA-Z$_][a-zA-Z$_0-9]* - {/ {} else { drop {} }`. The big regex is the equivalent regex for `JAVACLASS`.

Comment: I would not expect that to be much faster since it still does the regexp match on every line. But it did make me realize that dissect might be an option, so I added that to my answer.